# Socket.io-objc 400 (Handshake Error) Remote Server vs. localhost

Tags: objective-c, node.js, sockets, azure, socket.io

When I connect to Socket.io on the server I get a 400 error, but I don't see any errors connecting to localhost. (same code and connecting via socket.io-objc)

I'm using Azure to host the node.js project.
(I also have websockets on in the azure config if that makes a difference)

```
ERROR: handshake failed ... The request timed out.
onError() Error Domain=SocketIOError Code=-6 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(SocketIOError error -6.)" UserInfo=0x1874cc00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1870cad0 "The request timed out."}
```

Server Code (On Azure)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('express')(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
redis = require("redis"),
Primus = require('primus'),
kue = require("kue");

var haversine = require('haversine')
var finish = require("finish");
var client = redis.createClient(12276, "redis url");

client.auth('password');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);




io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.emit('join', { status: 'connected' });

});



var port = process.env.port || 1337;
server.listen(port);
```

SOCKET.IO-OBJC CODE

```
- (void) reconnect
{
    [socketIO disconnectForced];
    socketIO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    socketIO.useSecure = NO;
    [socketIO connectToHost:@"siteurl" onPort:80];
}
```

Comment: You should post your node.js code where you initialize the io object and set it to listen to a port, and also your client code/configs that tell us what it's trying to connect to and how.

Comment: @Houseman I just edited the original post to show what I currently have on Azure (I stripped a lot of the code out just to see if I could connect). I am able to connect with this via JavaScript, but unable to connect via Socket.io-objc.

For the client code I am using the example socket.io project and connecting on port 80.

Comment: connecting on port 80?? But your port is 1337 in your server code. can you post part of the client code where you're connecting to server??

Comment: As M Omayr said, you should be connecting to the same port that your server is listening on. If your sockets are listening over port 1337, then that's what your client sockets should be connecting to.

Comment: @MOmayr I'm connecting on the Azure port (process.env.port  - it's port 80). It works with JavaScript and C# just not with Socket.io-objc

Comment: @MOmayr I just updated the original post to show the code that I'm using for socket.io-objc

Comment: @Houseman I believe Azure only connects node.js via port 80. (from what I've seen)